# How do I implement a text input section along with the send button in juggernaut?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dialog, chatroom, juggernaut, faye

I have followed the exact guidelines on github and I am on the final step of:

"That's it! Now go to http://localhost:8080 to see Juggernaut in action."

A dialog box is displayed.  However, I am unable to write any text.

I would like to be able to fix up the page for practical chat usage instead of just testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to follow the guide on the Juggernaut readme under that line titled Basic Usage.

> Basic usage
>
> Everything in Juggernaut is done within the context of a channel.
>   JavaScript clients can subscribe to a channel which your server can
>   publish to. First, we need to include Juggernaut's application.js
>   file. By default, Juggernaut is hosted on port 8080 - so we can just
>   link to the file there.
>
> ```
> <script src="http://localhost:8080/application.js"
> ```
>
> type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
>
> We then need to instantiate the Juggernaut object and subscribe to the
>   channel. As you can see, subscribe takes two arguments, the channel
>   name and a callback.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
>   var jug = new Juggernaut;
>   jug.subscribe("channel1", function(data){
>     console.log("Got data: " + data);
>   });
> </script>
> ```
>
> That's it for the client side. Now, to publish to the channel we'll
>   write some Ruby:
>
> ```
> require "juggernaut"
> Juggernaut.publish("channel1", "Some data")
> ```
>
> You should see the data we sent appear instantly in the open browser
>   window. As well as strings, we can even pass objects, like so:
>
> ```
> Juggernaut.publish("channel1", {:some => "data"})
> ```
>
> The publish method also takes an array of channels, in case you want
>   to send a message to multiple channels co-currently.
>
> ```
> Juggernaut.publish(["channel1", "channel2"], ["foo", "bar"])
> ```
>
> That's pretty much the gist of it, the two methods - publish and
>   subscribe. Couldn't be easier than that!

Once you have that done you can implement the Ruby code mentioned above inside a controller which takes the user input from a form and then calls something like `Juggernaut.publish("channel1", @user_data)` allowing your users to send data through the server to each other.
`

Comment: Thanks, I've gotten irb to test out the text.
Can you further explain how I would add it to the controller to allow USERS to use it?

Comment: You need a form which submits to a controller the contents of a message. The controller then receives the text and calls the method to publish the text.